# Password is not verifying when user is login

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Here is my controller. Only the else part is executing in if loop. How to verify the password when user input the password?

The following function is not returning true and I do not understand why. I'm not getting any database errors but it definitely returns false for some reason. The table and field names are correct.

```
public function auth()
{
    $session = session();
    $model = new contactModel();
    $email = $this->request->getVar('email');
    $password = md5($this->request->getVar('password'));
    $data = $model->where('email', $email)->first();
    if($data){
        $pass = $data['password'];
        $verify_pass = password_verify($password, $pass);
        if($verify_pass){
            $ses_data = [
                'id'       => $data['id'],
                'name'     => $data['name'],
                'email'    => $data['email'],
                'message'  => $data['message'],
                'logged_in'     => TRUE
            ];
            $session->set($ses_data);
            return redirect()->to('/index.php/dashboard');
        }else{
            $session->setFlashdata('msg', 'Wrong Password');
            return redirect()->to('/index.php/login');
        }
    }else{
        $session->setFlashdata('msg', 'Email not Found');
        return redirect()->to('/index.php/login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$password = md5($this->request->getVar('password'));`

to

`$password = password_hash($this->request->getVar('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`.

`password_verify` doesn't just work on any hash, it needs algorithm and salt information too; this is the kind of stuff that `password_hash` deals with for you.

```
php > $hash = md5('abc123');
php > var_dump(password_verify('abc123', $hash));
php shell code:1:
bool(false)
php > $hash = password_hash('abc123', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
php > var_dump(password_verify('abc123', $hash));
php shell code:1:
bool(true)
```

This also addresses the fact that ***under no circumstances should you ever be using MD5 to obfuscate passwords.***

Comment: anyone can help me please.

Comment: @RashidKhalid Then you have a different problem on top of that.

Comment: @RashidKhalid I thought this would be assumed but you also need to make the same change to whatever code stores the password hash in the first place because that's probably still using `md5()`. Instead, generate that (and all password hashes) with `password_hash`, like above.